# Selenium code to read the value from HTML (WebScraping)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Am trying to read few values from website. I want to read the Value of Number of Articles from the below website. I want to store the value 1 in a variable to be used later. Am stuck here and not able to proceed further. Any help is much appreciated.
[image]

Below is the screen shot of the HTML code when I press inspect element on Number of articles.
[image]

I have tried the below codes but for no use

```
mBrowser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$TxtTotLines").text
mBrowser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$TxtTotLines").Value
```

Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the attribute value you have to use get_attribute function and specify in parameter the attribute that you want to read.

In your case it will be :

```
mBrowser.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$TxtTotLines").get_attribute('value')
```

You can have more details here : [Selenium API documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html)